# C++ Making tuple from two tuples by randomly choosing their elements

Tags: c++, c++11, random, tuples, c++14

**WHAT I WANT EXACTLY:** I have a pair of tuples with unknown types and unknown number of arguments, but types of these two tuples and variable count is exactly the same, e.g.:

```
std::pair<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::tuple<Ts...>>
```

**Let's call those tuples A and B**

Now I want to make a new tuple from those two with the exactly same types and argument count (`std::tuple<Ts...>`) in the following way:

**1. Randomly choose tuple A or B for an element** (I guess I can do it by calling std::experimental::rand_int(0,1) or another generator).

**2. Place this element in new tuple (let's call it C)** (maybe std::experimental::apply could be of any help to point **2.** and **3.**?)

**3. Repeat steps 1-2 until the end of tuple A and B**

***EXAMPLE:***

```
A = std::tuple<double, int, long, int> {2.7, 1, 22, 4};
B = std::tuple<double, int, long, int> {12.4, 7, -19, 18};
```

After algorithm I want to receive, for example:

```
C = std::tuple<double, int, long, int> {12.4, 1, 22, 18};
```

(or any other combination of A and B following this scheme)

Comment: Just do it recursively. Do you need code?

Comment: @SergeyA As I'm better with C++ theory and didn't have much practice as of now it would really help me if you have enough time.

Comment: The suggestions you give seem okay, what part are you stuck on exactly?

Comment: I will provide a code in a few :)

Comment: @GuyGreer Getting recursive algorithm with std::experimental::apply which takes both of tuples and randomizes whether to choose element from A or from B and putting it in tuple C.

Comment: @SergeyA Is there a way to do it without external functions, e.g. lampda and using algorithms I have mentioned above?

Comment: @KerrekSB has already done it, before I was able to publish my version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shouldn't be too hard:

```
template <typename Tuple, std::size_t ...I>
Tuple rand_tuple_aux(const Tuple & a, const Tuple & b, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return Tuple(std::get<I>(flip_coin() ? a : b)...);
}

template <typename ...Args>
std::tuple<Args...> rand_tuple(const std::tuple<Args...> & a,
                               const std::tuple<Args...> & b)
{
    return rand_tuple_aux(a, b, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>());
}
```

Comment: `index_sequence_for<Args...>()` is shorter here

Comment: @GuyGreer: I had no idea that existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know there's a marked answer so I won't change it, but I wanted to add my solution (it's quite hackish so not really advised, but I wanted to make this function a lambda). 
**Parents type:**

```
std::pair<std::pair<std::tuple<Ts...>>, std::pair<std::tuple<Ts...>>>
```

(that's why I've used auto...)

**Here's the code:**

```
auto generate_child=[&](const auto& parents){
            auto genotype=std::experimental::apply(
                    [&](const auto&... mother){
                        return std::experimental::apply(
                                [&](const auto&... father){
                                    return std::make_tuple(
                                            (std::experimental::randint(0,1)?mother:father)...
                                    );
                                },
                                parents.second.second
                        );
                    },
                    parents.first.second
            );
            return std::make_pair(
                    std::experimental::apply(function,genotype),
                    genotype
            );
        };
```